# Why FireFox can't play long videos (.mp4 2GB+) on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video

I was testing html5 video on firefox, I tried to play large (.mp4) 720p HD file. But Firefox crashes and unable to play video.

Same HTML5 video works perfect on Google Chrome,

Have a look here: http://goo.gl/FiAE6j